# SonarQube does not reflect the latest version

Tags: sonarqube

We are using Gitlab CI/CD to deploy and to check via SonarQube. Our flow:
dev branch -> merge into release with preview mode ON -> accumulate new code in release branch -> create tag when finished -> merge into master without preview.
So far it was okay, Sonar recognized somehow current version (from tag) and showed it in the app
[image]

But then it becomes weird and it went back from 1.6.0 to 1.5.0, same time showing “new code from 1.6”

[image]

I tried to pass along `-Dsonar.projectVersion` or `-Dsonar.scm.revision` during our Gradle tasks, but nothing changes. How can I manually (via Gradle task) set this version to the one I desire?

Comment: are you using the gradle task to build your project or how do you trigger the analysis, just because you want to manipulate the version does not mean you are using the official gradle plugin. Do you have any sonar-project.properties, which would be worth sharing, due to configuration? are there other builds, still pushing to the same branch, but with an outdated version?

Comment: I solved the problem. During CI/CD the $VERSION env variable was created during another stage and did not pass through stages, so `-Dsonar.projectVersion` were empty =)